# Renaming command line windows

Tags: windows, command-line

I am using windows 10 and would like to rename a number of files which are in the directory `C:\temp\bildgroesse`.
The files are named `test1.tif`, `test2.tif` and so on.

So I wrote the command line:

```
cd \temp\bildgroesse
rename C:\temp\bildgroesse\ *.tif *-org.tif
```

I also tried :

```
cd \temp\bildgroesse
rename C:\temp\bildgroesse\ * *-org
```

The result is in both cases:`test1.tif_org.tif`,`test2.tif_org.tif` and so on. So Windows takes the extension as filename.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your formulation used to work in previous versions of Windows,
so I would really define it as a new bug in Windows 10.

You could instead use the
[forfiles command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551(v=ws.11).aspx) like this :

```
forfiles /M *.tif /C "cmd /c ren @file @fname-org.tif"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `forfiles` solution, but this is how to add a string to a file name before its extension using only the `rename` command.

```
ren *.ext ????????????string.ext
```

So in your case, you would use

```
cd \temp\bildgroesse
ren *.tif ????????????-org.tif
```

Notes:

- This does **not** work the same if a file has more than one `.` in its name. The question mark wildcard matches a single character as long as that character is not `.`, so only the characters before the first `.` will appear in the new file name. The `forfiles` solution has no such restriction.
- The number of question marks needs to be greater than or equal to the length of the longest file name (without its extension).
- Once you `cd` to a directory, you do not need to type out the full path to the files. Alternatively, if you type out the full path, you do not need to `cd`.
- `ren` is an alias for `rename`.

More information on `ren`/`rename`, including wildcard usage, can be found [here](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html).